# classCastException in Map.Entry

Tags: java, generics

there is something about my code that i dont understand.
when i execute the following code className1 and value1 get their value right from the entry, but when for the className2 i am getting ClassCastException Date can not be cast to a String when processing an entry with getValue = {java.util.Date@11632}"Sun Jun 01 00:00:00 PDT 1997"

```
String key1="", className1="", value1="";
String key2="", className2="", value2="";
Object obj;

Map<String, String> inputValues = reportOptions.getInputValues();
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry: inputValues.entrySet()){
    key1 = entry.getKey().toString();
    obj = entry.getValue();
    className1 = obj.getClass().getName();
    value1 = obj.toString();

    className2 = entry.getValue().getClass().getName();
    value2 = entry.getValue().toString();
}
```

should be simple but i am missing it...

Comment: can you show us the code that populates the inputValues map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing this is because your map that you get isn't actually a `Map<String,String>` but rather a `Map<String,Date>`.

Answer (score 1):

In `reportOptions.getInputValues()` you have some unsafe cast, or you are using raw types, and your map actually contains `<String, Date>` rather than `<String, String>`.

Answer (score 0):

To find the bug, use Collections.checkedMap so that the program blows up exactly where the bad data enters the map:

```
java.util.HashMap map = new java.util.HashMap();
map.put(new Integer(4), new Integer(7)); // OK - HashMap does not care, nor does Java

java.util.Map safeMap = java.util.Collections.checkedMap(map,String.class,String.class);
safeMap.put(new Integer(6), new Integer(9)); // WILL blow up!
```